# How to use variable of function for another one? (Python)

Tags: python, function, variables, tic-tac-toe

I am a beginner in Python. I started to write some code for a game called 'Tic tac toe'.
For that I created some functions below:

```py
import random
def choose_first():
    random.randint(1, 2)
    if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
        print('Player 1 is first to play')
        player1_input()
    elif random.randint(1,2) == 2:
        print('Player 2 is first to play')
        player2_input()

def player1_input():
    player1=''
    marker=''
    while marker !='X' and marker !='O':
        marker=input('Player 1, choose X or O: ')
        return marker
    player1==marker
    if player1=='X':
        player2='O'
    else:
        player2='X'
    return (player1,player2,marker)

def player_choice(board):
    position = int(input('Which position you want to choose? '))
    if space_check is True:
        return position

def place_marker(board, marker, position):
     board[position] = marker
```

Here is piece of code that using those functions:

```py
def game_on():
    board = ['#','','','','','','','','','']
    choose_first()
    while not full_board_check(board): 
        player_choice(board)
        place_marker(board, marker, position)
        display_board(board)
    while full_board_check(board):
        if win_check(board, mark):
            print('Player using', marker, 'won')
        else:
            print("It's a tie!")
```

When I choosing position it returns this error:

```
<ipython-input-117-d37edecdd743> in game_on()
      5     while not full_board_check(board):
      6         player_choice(board)
----> 7         place_marker(board, marker, position)
      8         display_board(board)
      9     while full_board_check(board):

NameError: name 'marker' is not defined
```

It seems that the 'marker' variable doesn't return from `player_input()` but I need to use him at another function (in this situation for placing marker). How to do that? Please help if you can.

Comment: You never use the returned values. You should have something like `player1, player2, marker = player_input()`. Note that the variable names used in the function are local to the function, so unrelated to the names used in the code that calls it.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you should do is to put `global marker` before getting the input:

```
global marker
marker=input('Player 1, choose X or O: ')
```